# Restrict Selected Cells to Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code so that users can only select one cell at a time in a sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I am looking to apply this only to certain ListObject Ranges inside the sheet, e.g.

```
Range("table_1[Codes]")
Range("table_2[Names]")
Range("table_3[Cities]")
```

so then the user can freely select multiple cells outside those ListObject Ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) to test if the `Target` is in another range.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("table_1[Codes]")) Is Nothing _
Or Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("table_2[Names]")) Is Nothing _
Or Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("table_3[Cities]")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

Alternatively to the `Or` you could also use `Union`:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Me.Range("table_1[Codes]"), Me.Range("table_2[Names]"), Me.Range("table_3[Cities]"))) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If
```

If you want it to be safe agains errors like one of the tables in the list does not exist you must use some error handling:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeNames() As Variant
    RangeNames = Array("table_1[Codes]", "table_2[Names]", "table_3[Cities]", "this does not exist")

    Dim RangeName As Variant, TestRange As Range
    For Each RangeName In RangeNames
        Set TestRange = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set TestRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Range(RangeName))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not TestRange Is Nothing Then
            Target.Range("A1").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next RangeName
End Sub
```

If one of the named tables does not exist this code still works for the others.

Comment: Isn't OP looking to have users selecting one cell only in these ranges, and if more than one cell it should go to A1? Or maybe I misinterpret the question.

Comment: @JvdV `Target.Range("A1").Select` goes to the first cell of `Target` (the selection) not to `A1` of the worksheet! The range address system is counting relatively to `Target` here. So if a user selects `A5:A10` this line selects `A5` only. • Since he stated *"I am looking to apply this only to certain ListObject Ranges inside the sheet."* obviously his code is working on the complete sheet and he want it only to run on the specific ranges.

Comment: sorry this code doesn't work for me. For those ranges, I only want the user to be able to select 1 cell only at a time within those ranges.

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Sorry obviously I got the intersect wrong. See my edited answer.

Comment: Right @Pᴇʜ, now that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. I misinterpreted the question myself. Nice piece of code :)